# Cannot open URL (works otherwise in web)in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load a dataset directly from kaggle (without having to download it on my local machine first). For this, I referred different solutions on stackoverflow to come up with the following code:

```
library(httr)
dataset <- httr::GET("https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/heart-failure-prediction/download/", 
                 httr::authenticate("kguliani", authkey, type = "basic"))
# destination file 
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(dataset$url,temp)
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "heart.csv"))
unlink(temp)
head(data)
```

I believe it should work but I keep getting the error message:

```
Error in download.file(dataset$url, temp): cannot open URL 'https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/heart-failure-prediction/download'
```

This URL works just fine in the web and lets me download the `archive.zip`(that contains the target file `'heart.csv'`) file. Can someone pls guide me to why the url is not working?

(I edited the question to take out my authkey since I wasn't sure if I should share it). To reproduce, feel free to use your username and authkey instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After researching on [Kaggle API](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api), I found that the base url that they are using are a bit different than the actual link for retrieving the zip file. The format is as follow,

`https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/datasets/download/{owner_slug}/{dataset_slug}`

I also added the argument `mode="wb"` to the `download.file` function as it was corrupting without it as stated [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/download-file-issue-corrupted-file/60844).

```
library(httr)

dataset <- httr::GET("https://www.kaggle.com/api/v1/datasets/download/fedesoriano/heart-failure-prediction", 
                 httr::authenticate("kguliani", authkey, type = "basic"))

# destination file 
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")

download.file(dataset$url, temp, mode = "wb")

data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "heart.csv"))

unlink(temp)

head(data)
```

Result:

```
Age Sex ChestPainType RestingBP Cholesterol FastingBS RestingECG MaxHR ExerciseAngina Oldpeak
1  40   M           ATA       140         289         0     Normal   172              N     0.0
2  49   F           NAP       160         180         0     Normal   156              N     1.0
3  37   M           ATA       130         283         0         ST    98              N     0.0
4  48   F           ASY       138         214         0     Normal   108              Y     1.5
5  54   M           NAP       150         195         0     Normal   122              N     0.0
6  39   M           NAP       120         339         0     Normal   170              N     0.0
  ST_Slope HeartDisease
1       Up            0
2     Flat            1
3       Up            0
4     Flat            1
5       Up            0
6       Up            0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for helping me out! One follow-up: are you able to finally extract the csv file into the data variable? For me, it keeps showing 'no lines in input' when I try to reproduce the above code and the api format you mentioned doesn't work in web.

Comment: data is showing correctly in my end. Double-check your username and auth key as well was adding the argument `mode="wb"` in the `download.file` function. I added the result of the `head(data)` after retrieving the `csv` file

Comment: Hmm that's quite strange. I'm still unable to get past this and already did everything you mentioned.

Comment: What version of R are you using, and what OS?

Comment: I'm using R 4.2.0 with Windows 11 installed.